# How to suggest new Bounty reasons?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

The current Bounty reasons are:

- Authoritative reference needed
- Canonical answer required
- Current answers are outdated
- Draw attention
- Improve details
- Reward existing answer

The one item that I would have preferred to use on each Bounty that I have started is:

- None of the current answers provide an adequate solution.

Sometimes the obvious third and fourth choices can substitute, sometimes not. Please add this additional Bounty reason so that myself and other bounty-prey might properly label our questions.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add an additional explanation, on top of the bounty reason. So, choose reason 5, and as a bounty remark: "None of the current answers provide an adequate solution.", or something.

Answer (score 7):

How does the fifth notice not fit what you're looking for?

> **Improve details**
>
> The current answers do not contain enough detail.

Bear in mind that this doesn't imply a restriction to awarding the bounty to existing answers. New answers may be added if editing any of the existing answers just doesn't cut it. Plus, only new answers with a score of at least 2 will qualify for an automatically-awarded bounty.

If you need to elaborate on how exactly the current answers don't provide adequate solutions, as Rob W mentions you can add an additional description to go with the bounty reason.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but sometimes there are _no_ answers. So that precludes number five. And before you suggest number four, note that the question may have a few upvotes.

Comment: Or at least rephrase the bounty reason: "The current answers are inadequate or don't contain enough detail."